# how to login to a site like this?

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android app to login to my internet provider website and then read my 3g data comsumption.

(It's a https website: https://www.simyo.es/simyo/portal/customer/action/my-panel)

I'm able to read the website with the code I put at the end of this post.

But... I don't know how to introduce my username/password and then do submit.

Any idea?

(Sorry for my poor english)

Thank you

**EasySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
package com.javimoya.test;

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.net.InetAddress;  
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;  
import java.net.Socket;  
import java.net.UnknownHostException;  

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;  
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;  
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;  

import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;  
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory;  
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory;  
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;  
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;  

public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory 
{  
    private SSLContext sslcontext = null;  

    private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException 
    {  
      try
      {  
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");  
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);  
        return context;  
      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {  
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());  
      }  
    }  

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException 
    {  
      if (this.sslcontext == null) 
      {  
        this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();  
      }  
      return this.sslcontext;  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int, 
     *      java.net.InetAddress, int, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams) 
     */  
    public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock,
                                    String host,
                                    int port, 
                                    InetAddress localAddress,
                                    int localPort,
                                    HttpParams params) 

                throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException 
    {  
      int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);  
      int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);  
      InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);  
      SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());  

      if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) 
      {  
        // we need to bind explicitly  
        if (localPort < 0) 
        {  
          localPort = 0; // indicates "any"  
        }  
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);  
        sslsock.bind(isa);  
      }  

      sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);  
      sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);  
      return sslsock;    
    }  

    /** 
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket() 
     */  
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {  
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket) 
     */  
    public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {  
        return true;  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int, 
     *      boolean) 
     */  
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket,
                                   String host, 
                                   int port,
                                   boolean autoClose) throws IOException,  
                                                             UnknownHostException 
    {  
      return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);  
    }  

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------  
    // javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :  
    // Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden  
    // for the correct operation of some connection managers  
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------  

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
        return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(EasySSLSocketFactory.class));  
    }  

    public int hashCode() {  
        return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();  
    }  
}
```

**EasyX509TrustManager.java**

```
package com.javimoya.test;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager 
{  
    private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;  

    /** 
     * Constructor for EasyX509TrustManager. 
     */  
    public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException 
    {  
      super();  
      TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());  
      factory.init(keystore);  
      TrustManager[] trustmanagers = factory.getTrustManagers();  
      if (trustmanagers.length == 0) 
      {  
        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("no trust manager found");  
      }  
      this.standardTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustmanagers[0];  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType) 
     */  
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException 
    {  
      standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);  
    }  

    /** 
     * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[],String authType) 
     */  
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType) throws CertificateException 
    {  
    // Clean up the certificates chain and build a new one.
        // Theoretically, we shouldn't have to do this, but various web servers
        // in practice are mis-configured to have out-of-order certificates or
        // expired self-issued root certificate.
        int chainLength = certificates.length;
        if (certificates.length > 1) 
        {
          // 1. we clean the received certificates chain.
          // We start from the end-entity certificate, tracing down by matching
          // the "issuer" field and "subject" field until we can't continue.
          // This helps when the certificates are out of order or
          // some certificates are not related to the site.
          int currIndex;
          for (currIndex = 0; currIndex < certificates.length; ++currIndex) 
          {
            boolean foundNext = false;
            for (int nextIndex = currIndex + 1;
                           nextIndex < certificates.length;
                           ++nextIndex) 
            {
              if (certificates[currIndex].getIssuerDN().equals(
                            certificates[nextIndex].getSubjectDN())) 
              {
                foundNext = true;
                // Exchange certificates so that 0 through currIndex + 1 are in proper order
                if (nextIndex != currIndex + 1) 
                {
                  X509Certificate tempCertificate = certificates[nextIndex];
                  certificates[nextIndex] = certificates[currIndex + 1];
                  certificates[currIndex + 1] = tempCertificate;
                }
                break;
            }
            }
            if (!foundNext) break;
      }

          // 2. we exam if the last traced certificate is self issued and it is expired.
          // If so, we drop it and pass the rest to checkServerTrusted(), hoping we might
          // have a similar but unexpired trusted root.
          chainLength = currIndex + 1;
          X509Certificate lastCertificate = certificates[chainLength - 1];
          Date now = new Date();
          if (lastCertificate.getSubjectDN().equals(lastCertificate.getIssuerDN())
                  && now.after(lastCertificate.getNotAfter())) 
          {
            --chainLength;
          }
      } 

    standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);    
    }  

    /** 
     * @see javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager#getAcceptedIssuers() 
     */  
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() 
    {  
      return this.standardTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();  
    }    
}
```

**MyHttpClient.java**

```
package com.javimoya.test;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.content.Context;

public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient 
{    
  final Context context;

  public MyHttpClient(HttpParams hparms, Context context)
  {
    super(hparms);
    this.context = context;     
  }

  @Override
  protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

    // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
    // to the ConnectionManager
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));

    //http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/android-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }
}
```

**MySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
package com.javimoya.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

**TestActivity.java**

```
package com.javimoya.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);


        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        int timeoutConnection = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        // Instantiate the custom HttpClient
        HttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(httpParameters,
                                             getApplicationContext());
      //HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://eu.battle.net/login/en/login.xml");
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.simyo.es/simyo/portal/customer/action/my-panel");

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try 
        {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
          sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String page = sb.toString();
        //System.out.println(page);

        tv.setText(page);
            }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        finally
        {
        if (in != null) 
        {
          try
          {
            in.close();
          }
          catch (IOException e) 
          {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }                       
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.simyo.es/simyo/portal/customer/action/my-panel");
```

Do a

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://www.simyo.es/simyo/portal/j_security_check");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "PUT_USERNAME_HERE"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "PUT_PASSWORD_HERE"));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
client.execute(request);
```